can a trademark for a pre-launch app be in use-in-commerce status?
https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks/apply/basis
According to the USPTO:
"A mark is in use in commerce with services when (1) the mark is used in the sale, advertising, or rendering of the services, and (2) the services are actually being rendered in commerce."

So according to the second condition (2), the app would have to be launched, correct?
So therefore, it is not possible for a pre-launch app to be Use in Commerce?

Planned use suffices for registration
Assume I want to trademark "Widget" in seal grey on light blue for the uniforms of Widget Corp. I file my trademark and then order the uniforms. Trademark law gives me the time to do that, and only checks if I actually use the uniforms in commerce some time later.
Why? Because 15 USC 1051 (b) explicitly is about being able to register a mark before its use if you have a real intent to use it, and once one gets the go-ahead from the USPTO, one gets 6 months to prove that one started using it... or lose it.
Advertisement, uniforms or even stickers on taxis are in use.
Trademarks denote the origin of a product and want to distinguish it from others. As soon as you show your product or company to the market, such as with ads showing a product in development or a company logo on your door, you can trademark that. See also your other question.
Why? That's because it is defined to be so in 15 USC 1127:

a mark shall be deemed to be in use in commerce
(2) on services when it is used or displayed in the sale or advertising of services and the services are rendered in commerce, or the services are rendered in more than one State or in the United States and a foreign country and the person rendering the services is engaged in commerce in connection with the services.


I am aware of "intent to use". But I cannot predict whether that will be 6 months or a few years, hence I am asking about actual use in commerce.

You asked about what is use here.. Anything said there applies here.
